# Dar 100% pantalla en web responsive

Tags: css3

Tengo estas medidas en normal

```
.centrar{
    width:65%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

en el responsive pongo

```
@media (max-width:800px){
  .centrar{
        width: 100% !important;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid;
        margin: 0 auto;
    } 
}
```

y no me coge el 100% de la pantalla. Alguna sugerencia? o debería hacerlo con javascript?

Comment: Un detalle: width:100% indica que el elemento debe usar el 100% del ancho de su contenedor padre, no de la pantalla o del documento. Puedes probar a usar width: 100vw

Answer (score 1):

Tu código funciona correctamente, mira que el archivo css se esté cargando en tu web, o que la ruta sea la adecuada.

Anotar que `width:100%;` significa el 100% del contenedor padre, no tiene por qué significar de toda la pantalla.

Te dejo un ejemplo de tu código funcionando:

```css
.centrar{ 
width:65%; 
margin:auto; 
text-align:center; 
color:blue;
}  
@media (max-width:800px){ 
  .centrar{ 
  width: 100% !important; 
  height:80px; 
  border:1px solid; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="centrar">
ABCD
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿En qué situación no te funciona?

Aquí tienes un ejemplo ampliado que juega con el ancho y el color del borde. Si lo ejecutas y cambias el tamaño de la ventana del navegador deberías ver cómo se aplican las diferentes media queries:

```css
.centrar{
    width:65%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  .centrar{
        width: 100%;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px){
  .centrar{
    width: 80%;
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 200px){
  .centrar{
    width: 50%;
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="centrar"></div>
```